# How to dynamically draw bitmaps to a Canvas in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

Here is the scenario of the issue . 
A custom view which is a canvas on which I need to draw .
2 buttons beneath it ,lets call them A and B 
When A is clicked -> Image A is drawn to the above canvas .
When B is clicked -> Image B is drawn to the above canvas .

The issue demands that the previously drawn image on canvas must be preserved . That is if you click button A followed by button B then the canvas must contain two images . So the previous images need to be preserved.

Problem : How do you achieve this ? 
Possible solution 1 : Create an ArrayList and keep adding images to this arrayList . Pass the updated arrayList to canvas onDraw method and redraw every single image for every button click .

Possible solution 2 : There has to be some method to preserve the state of the canvas so that on each button click you draw on canvas's last preserved state and draw only the new image .

Further Requirements : The Images drawn to canvas could be dragged so need to keep track of updated positions .

I am at an impasse and couldn't find a good tutorial or a book tackling such requirement , any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 2):

You can create the Bitmap, and draw what you want on it.

```
Bitmap mBitmap;

protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (changed) {
        if (mBitmap != null) {
            mBitmap.recycle();
            mBitmap = null;
        }
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(right - left, bottom - top, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        redrawAllYourStuffTo(mBitmap);
    }
}
```

when button is pressed, you can draw directly to bitmap, like this:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
canvas. ... // draw operations.

// after the bitmap canvas drawing finished, call
invalidate();
```

in *onDraw* just paint your bitmap

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: Hey , thanks it worked . Now moving on to the further requirement part that is dragging images around . I think I will have to redraw canvas for every translation that I make on these bitmaps . For that I need to create an array list of Bitmaps and keep drawing them again for every call to onDraw method . Is there any better approach ?

Comment: If amount of moveable elements is significant (i.e. it takes long time to redraw them every frame), you can create two bitmap. When movement starts, draw all underlying images on one, all overlying on another. In onDraw you can draw them just painting bottom bitmap, then moveable image, then top bitmap. After movement is finished, combine them back again. That could significantly improve UI response and user experience.

Comment: Thanks , I will try this . The thing is I could be having dynamic number of images and I need to keep track of every single Image co-ordinates . The images could even be scaled or rotated , thats the final goal . I was wondering when so many games are developed , even those developers must be encountering the same issue of handling every single sprite. How do they achieve it ? Do they draw every sprite for every change on the canvas ? In my case too every bitmap is just like an individual sprite .